# spring-mvc: error mapping url for form controller

Tags: spring-mvc

i have a problem with spring mvc

my spring bean

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

<bean id="urlMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="welcome.htm">welcomeController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean name="welcomeController"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
    p:viewName="welcome" />

<bean name="/bscList.htm" class="cbs.web.BscController">
    <property name="bscDao" ref="myBscDao" />
</bean>

<bean name="/bscForm.htm" class="cbs.web.BscFormController">
    <property name="commandName" value="bsc"/>
    <property name="commandClass" value="cbs.domain.Bsc"/>
    <property name="formView" value="bscForm"/>
    <property name="successView" value="bscList.htm"/>
    <property name="bscDao" ref="myBscDao"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

my form controller

```
public class BscFormController extends SimpleFormController {

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BscController.class);
private BscDao bscDao;

public void setBscDao(BscDao bscDao) {
    this.bscDao = bscDao;
}

protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    String id = request.getParameter("id");

    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(id)) {
        return bscDao.get(new Integer(id));
    }

    return new Bsc();
}

public ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {
    log.debug("entering 'onSubmit' method...");

    Bsc bsc = (Bsc) command;
    String success = getSuccessView();

    if (request.getParameter("delete") != null) {
        bscDao.remove(bsc.getId());
    } else {
        bscDao.save(bsc);
    }

    return new ModelAndView(success);
}
}
```

my problem:
when I access /bscList.htm, it's display list of bsc (bscList.jsp template), 
but when I access /bscForm.htm, it's still display bsc's list, not show my form (bscForm.jsp template)

I have test with some simple controller:

- controller implement org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller, evething run fine
- controller extends SimpleFormController, map error:
  No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/cbs/testform.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Answer (score 0):

when i use HandlerMapping ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping, all request URL '/bsc*' will map to BscController (/bscForm.htm will not map to BscFormController)